# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

```
User::updateOrCreate([
    'identifier' => $user->id,
    'username' => $user->nickname,
    'name' => $user->name,
    'avatar' => $user->avatar,
    'visibility' => $user->visibility,
    'api_token' => Uuid::generate()
]);
```

And my migration:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('identifier')->unique();
    $table->string('username')->unique();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('avatar');
    $table->string('trade')->nullable();
    $table->decimal('funds')->default(0);
    $table->enum('visibility', [1, 2, 3]);
    $table->uuid('api_token');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

But results in a QueryException :(

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry
>   '76561198364059468' for key 'users_identifier_unique'

Comment: the error is pretty much self-explanatory. You may want to use INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error says that there is a row in the `users` table where `identifier` has value of `76561198364059468` already. So just use an unique identifier to avoid the error.

Comment: But I used updateOrCreate method. Should update the row. I'm not creating other row

Comment: @lai0n in this case you should pass `['identifier' => 76561198364059468]` as the first parameter in `updateOrCreate()`

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
User::updateOrCreate(
    [
        'identifier' => $user->id
    ],
    [
        'username' => $user->nickname,
        'name' => $user->name,
        'avatar' => $user->avatar,
        'visibility' => $user->visibility,
        'api_token' => Uuid::generate()
    ]
);
```